# Screen twitches on iPhone after some navigations

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm working on react-native app and I use react-native-router-flux. I found a strange behavior, specific for iOS only: when I switch before scenes, some elements twitches (see video). I found that it happens with scenes which have navigation bar only.

[Link to video](https://yadi.sk/i/dPAJqoMUg-Kt8w)

There is an example of code which will have twitching effect (property **hideNavBar** is false)

```
    import { Scene, Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux'

    const essentialProps = {
      backTitle: 'Back',
      navBar: CustomNavBar,
    }

    const AppNavigator = Actions.create(

      // ...

      <Scene
        key="notifications"
        path="/notifications"
        component={Notifications}
        hideNavBar={false}
        hideTabBar
        title="Notifications"
        {...essentialProps}
      />

    )
```

If scene has **hideNavBar** as true, elements will not jump. It doesn't related with redux store updating, I checked with react-native debugger.

Does anybody had this problem? I'm a beginner in react-native, so I could miss something.

Thanks.

Comment: You try remove `hideNavBar, hideTabBar `

Comment: I tried, but without `hideNavBar={false}` there is no Navigation bar at all.

Answer (score 0):

Found a reason: it's a bug related with navigation bar https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/3373